# echo in a bash script changing '--md5' to '?-md5'

Tags: bash, vmware, grub

I'm writing a VMWare ESX automated build script and I'm falling at the last hurdle, probably as I'm really not strong at scripting.

I need to secure Grub so in my script I have a like saying;

```
echo "password --md5 password-converted-to-md5" >> /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

This unfortunately places the following into this file;

```
password ?-md5 password-converted-to-md5
```

I know it's a simple one for some of you guys but I've been googling for hours and I'm getting frustrated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that both dashes in "--md5" are simple ASCII minus characters (U+002D)? You might accidentally have used U+2010 HYPEN "‐", U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPEN "‑" or any other similar character. Try deleting both dashes and re-typing them.

Comment: (note: this kind of error is relatively common when writing scripts in anything than a simple text editor, MS Word and similar tools are infamous for doing that kind of replacements that make sense in natural language text but mess up code)

Comment: I used MS Notepad but will now check using nano/vi - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have simple ascii dashes and not other chars like non-breaking-hyphen, mathematical-minus, en-dash, em-dash, etc. best is to just re-type your line, this will hopefully solve your problem

Comment: You were right, thank you - I'd written the script using MS notepad and for some reason the first hyphen was displayed fine in notepad but  as an accented 'u' in nano - lovely old MS eh! thanks again chaps.

Answer (score 1):

I would use simple quote and see if it's help:

```
echo 'password --md5 password-converted-to-md5' >> /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

or with a variable:

```
echo $passwordVar' --md5 password-converted-to-md5' >> /boot/grub/grub.conf
```